# Sequelize: on a subset of model A, sum an integer-attribute of an associated model B

Tags: sql, join, associations, subset, sequelize.js

**I want to do this:**

```
select sum("quantity") as "sum"
from "orderArticles" 
inner join "orders" 
on "orderArticles"."orderId"="orders"."id" 
and "orderArticles"."discountTagId" = 2
and "orders"."paid" is not null;
```

which results in on my data base:

```
 sum 
-----
 151

(1 row)
```

How can I do it?

**My Sequelize solution:**

The model definitions:

```
const order = Conn.define('orders', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        // ...
        paid: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: null
        },
        // ...
    },
// ...
})

const orderArticle = Conn.define('orderArticles', 
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        // ...

        quantity: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 1
        }
    },
    {
        scopes: {
            paidOrders: {
                include: [
                   { model: order, where: { paid: {$ne: null}} }
               ]
            }
        },
// ...
})
```

Associations:

```
orderArticle.belongsTo(order)
order.hasMany(orderArticle, {onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true})
```

I came up with this after hours of research:

```
db.models.orderArticles
 .scope('paidOrders') // select only orders with paid: {$ne: null}
 .sum('quantity', { // sum up all resulting quantities
    attributes: ['quantity'], // select only the orderArticles.quantity col
    where: {discountTagId: 2}, // where orderArticles.discountTagId = 2
    group: ['"order"."id"', '"orderArticles"."quantity"'] // don't know why, but Sequelize told me to
 })
.then(sum => sum) // return the sum
```

leads to this sql:

> SELECT "orderArticles"."quantity", sum("quantity") AS "sum",
>   "order"."id" AS "order.id", "order"."taxRate" AS "order.taxRate",
>   "order"."shippingCosts" AS "order.shippingCosts", "order"."discount"
>   AS "order.discount", "order"."paid" AS "order.paid",
>   "order"."dispatched" AS "order.dispatched", "order"."payday" AS
>   "order.payday", "order"."billNr" AS "order.billNr",
>   "order"."createdAt" AS "order.createdAt", "order"."updatedAt" AS
>   "order.updatedAt", "order"."orderCustomerId" AS
>   "order.orderCustomerId", "order"."billCustomerId" AS
>   "order.billCustomerId" FROM "orderArticles" AS "orderArticles" INNER
>   JOIN "orders" AS "order" ON "orderArticles"."orderId" = "order"."id"
>   AND "order"."paid" IS NOT NULL WHERE "orderArticles"."discountTagId" =
>   '4' GROUP BY "order"."id", "orderArticles"."quantity";

which has this result on the same data base: `0 rows`

If you know what I got wrong please let me know!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

in the scopes definition on the orderArticle model:

```
scopes: {
    paidOrders: {
        include: [{ 
            model: order, 
            where: { paid: {$ne: null}}, 
            attributes: [] // don't select additional colums!
        }]
    }
},
//...
```

and the algorithm:

```
db.models.orderArticles
    .scope('paidOrders')
    .sum('quantity', {
        attributes: [], // don't select any further cols
        where: {discountTagId: 2}
    })
```

Note: In my case it was sufficient to return the promise. I use GraphQL which resolves the result and sends it to the client.